# Sublime Text 2 unindents labels and access modifiers by default

Tags: sublimetext2, indentation, access-modifiers, auto-indent

How can I change that? I don't see any option in the preferences nor do I know of any plugin.

I want to avoid this style:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    void bar();
}
```

EDIT:

I'm using C++ and my style is like this:

```
class Foo
{
  private:      // Half tab (or two spaces)
    void bar(); // One tab
}
```

While I'm used to simply typing two spaces then `private:` and hit `Enter`,now I have to type `private:` hit `Enter` and navigate back to `private` to re-indent it. It's kind of a workflow kill.

Comment: Have you tried 'Paste and Indent'? It's under 'Edit' menu on Mac OS X.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you would like to see, as well as what language you are using.

Comment: @arin I don't see how 'Paste and Indent' is relevant. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I'm using ST3, and didn't have any issues. I type `class Foo`, then hit Enter. I then type an opening brace `{`, and it autocompletes the closing brace as well, with the cursor in between. I hit enter, it drops the closing brace down 2 lines, and drops the cursor down 1 line, indenting it 4 spaces. I hit Backspace, which sends the cursor to the beginning of the line, then type 2 spaces and `private:`. I then hit Enter, and the cursor is indented 4 spaces on the following line, ready to accept `void bar()` at the correct position.

Comment: @MattDMo But is there an option to keep the indentation so that `void bar()` can be twice indented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the best way to disable auto unindent on `public` `private` and `protected` keywords, by editing the `Indentation Rules.tmPreferences` file in Packages/C++. What I did is comment out the line:

```
|   ^ \s* (public|private|protected): \s* $
```

under the `decreaseIndentPattern` key.

Comment: Sublime Text 3 doesn't seem to have a Packages/C++ directory. How can I achieve this behaviour in ST3?

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answer isn't really complete, here in detail for anyone else:

1. Install Package Control: https://packagecontrol.io/installation.
2. Install PackageResourceViewer: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer
3. Open Command Palette in Sublime Text (Cmd + Shift + P on Mac)
4. Search for `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` and click Enter
5. In the new search panel type in `C++` and click Enter
6. In the next panel type in `Indentation Rules.tmPreferences` and  click Enter
7. In that file search for the line `|   ^ \s* (public|private|protected): \s* $` and comment it out by writing `<!--` in front of the line and `-->` at the end of the line. There might be two occurences of said line, for me it was enough to comment out the first one.

Note that the `public` following `private` now needs to be manually alined with `private` though. If somebody knows how to fix this please comment.